# I have identified the influencers in a network using pagerank and now i want to form communities around them using clustering coefficient

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import leidenalg
    from igraph import Graph as IGraph


    n = len(G1.nodes())

    # Initialize the community labels for each node
    community_labels = np.zeros(n)

    # Initialize a dictionary to store cluster sizes
    cluster_sizes = {}

    # Set threshold for local clustering coefficient similarity
    threshold = 1  # Adjust this threshold as needed

    # Initialize range counters
    range_counts = {
        "0-100": 0,
        "101-200": 0,
        "201-300": 0,
        "301-400": 0,
        "401-500": 0,
        ">500": 0,
    }

    clustering_coefficients = globals()["clustering_coefficients"]
    influencer_clustering_coefficients = {}

    # Loop over each influencer
    for influencer in influencers:
      if influencer in G:
        neighbors = G[influencer].keys()
      else:
        print(f"Influencer {influencer} not found in the graph.")
        continue

    # Extract relevant data for the influencer and its neighbors
    influencer_index = int(influencer)
    influencer_clustering_coefficient = clustering_coefficients.get(str(influencer_index), 0)
    neighbor_clustering_coefficients = [clustering_coefficients[n] for n in neighbors if n !=          influencer]
    neighbor_degrees = [G.degree(n) for n in neighbors if n != influencer]

    # Combine features for the Leiden algorithm
    features = np.array([influencer_clustering_coefficient, neighbor_clustering_coefficients,     neighbor_degrees])

    # Convert networkx graph to igraph graph
    ig = IGraph.TupleList(G.edges(), directed=True)

    # Run Leiden algorithm for community detection
    leiden_partition = leidenalg.find_partition(ig, leidenalg.ModularityVertexPartition)
    community_labels = np.array([int(label) for label in leiden_partition.membership])


    # Update cluster sizes and range counts
    for i in range(len(community_labels)):
        cluster_label = community_labels[i]
        size = cluster_sizes.get(cluster_label, 0)
        size += 1
        cluster_sizes[cluster_label] = size
    # Update range count
    if size <= 100:
        range_counts["0-100"] += 1
    elif size <= 200:
        range_counts["101-200"] += 1
    elif size <= 300:
        range_counts["201-300"] += 1
    elif size <= 400:
        range_counts["301-400"] += 1
    elif size <= 500:
        range_counts["401-500"] += 1
    else:
        range_counts[">500"] += 1

    # Print cluster size ranges and counts
    print("Cluster size ranges and counts:")
    for range, count in range_counts.items():
        print(f"- {range}: {count}")
```

I am getting this error

```
AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-424c5b4f70f8> in <cell line: 37>()
     48   try:
---> 49     influencer_clustering_coefficient = clustering_coefficients.get(str(influencer_index), 0)
     50   finally:

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
1 frames
<ipython-input-34-424c5b4f70f8> in <listcomp>(.0)
     49     influencer_clustering_coefficient = clustering_coefficients.get(str(influencer_index), 0)
     50   finally:
---> 51     neighbor_clustering_coefficients = [clustering_coefficients[n] for n in neighbors if n != influencer]
     52     neighbor_degrees = [G.degree(n) for n in neighbors if n != influencer]
     53 

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Now I am using Leiden algorithm, I have tried using Louvain algorithm as well but did not get any result, is there a better approach to form communities around influencers?`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You seem to have two separate (but similar) errors.  ```clustering_coefficients``` seems to be a ```float```.  Are you expecting it to be a dictionary?  What does ```globals()["clustering_coefficients"]``` look like?